# MongoDB shell command to delete element from nested array

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to delete elements in MongoDB nested array, based on its value...

Below is the insert query to load data to

```
db.records.insert({"key" : "ABC-111",
                "listChgLogs" : [ { 
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong("1543217249133"), 
                    "user" : "kopi", 
                    "changelog" : { 
                        "id" : "744683", 
                        "items" : [ { 
                            "field" : "Fix Version", 
                            "fieldtype" : "jira", 
                            "fieldId" : "fixVersions", 
                            "from" : "23555", 
                            "to" : null, 
                            "fromSting" : "Release 4.0.15", 
                            "toSting" : null 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            "field" : "Fix Version", 
                            "fieldtype" : "jira", 
                            "fieldId" : "fixVersions", 
                            "from" : null, 
                            "to" : "23539", 
                            "fromSting" : null, 
                            "toSting" : "Release 4.0.14" 
                        } ] 
                    } 
                }, 
                { 
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong("1542830553816"), 
                    "user" : "kaneshen", 
                    "changelog" : { 
                        "id" : "741833", 
                        "items" : [ { 
                            "field" : "status", 
                            "fieldtype" : "jira", 
                            "fieldId" : "status", 
                            "from" : "13516", 
                            "to" : "6", 
                            "fromSting" : "Log Work", 
                            "toSting" : "Closed" 
                        } ] 
                    } 
                }, 
                { 
                    "timestamp" : NumberLong("1542807125525"), 
                    "user" : "kaneshen", 
                    "changelog" : { 
                        "id" : "741526", 
                        "items" : [ {      "field" : "status", 
                            "fieldtype" : "jira", 
                            "fieldId" : "status", 
                            "from" : "10507", 
                            "to" : "6", 
                            "fromSting" : "In Review", 
                            "toSting" : "Closed" 
                        } ] 
                    } 
                } 
            ] 
            })
```

Now I want to delete the elements in "items" array when it has "field" : "Fix Version". Hence tried below queries in Mongo --shell.

```
db.records.update({"key" : "ABC-111"},{$pull: {"listChgLogs.changelog.items.fields": "Fix Version"}})

db.records.update({"key" : "ABC-111"},{$pull: {"listChgLogs.changelog.items": {"fields": "Fix Version"}}})
```

but I got error:

```
WriteResult({
"nMatched" : 0,
"nUpserted" : 0,
"nModified" : 0,
"writeError" : {
"code" : 28,
"errmsg" : "Cannot use the part (changelog) of (listChgLogs.changelog.items.fields) to traverse the element ({listChgLogs: [ { timestamp: 1543217249133, user: \"kopi\", changelog: { id: \"744683\", items: [ { field: \"Fix Version\", fieldtype: \"jira\", fieldId: \"fixVersions\", from: \"23555\", to: null, fromSting: \"Release 4.0.15\", toSting: null }, { field: \"Fix Version\", fieldtype: \"jira\", fieldId: \"fixVersions\", from: null, to: \"23539\", fromSting: null, toSting: \"Release 4.0.14\" } ] } }, { timestamp: 1542830553816, user: \"kaneshen\", changelog: { id: \"741833\", items: [ { field: \"status\", fieldtype: \"jira\", fieldId: \"status\", from: \"13516\", to: \"6\", fromSting: \"Log Work\", toSting: \"Closed\" } ] } }, { timestamp: 1542807125525, user: \"kaneshen\", changelog: { id: \"741526\", items: [ { field: \"status\", fieldtype: \"jira\", fieldId: \"status\", from: \"10507\", to: \"6\", fromSting: \"In Review\", toSting: \"Closed\" } ] } } ]})"
}
})
```

Similarly...

```
db.records.update({"key" : "ABC-111"},{$pull: {"listChgLogs": {"changelog": {"items": {"fields": "Fix Version"}}}}})

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

db.records.update({"key" : "ABC-111"},{$pull: {"listChgLogs.$.changelog.items": {"fields": "Fix Version"}}})

WriteResult({
"nMatched" : 0,
"nUpserted" : 0,
"nModified" : 0,
"writeError" : {
"code" : 2,
"errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query."
}
})
```

Not sure what I'm missing... Please help...